# How do I get back to the Material Plane if I get banished to the Feywild as a fairy?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes

I'm in a campaign, and I'm playing as a fairy cleric. We're level 3, so it's fairly reasonable that an enemy would be able to cast [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) relatively soon.

I don't get any spells that I know of that send me to a non-home plane until we get 7th-level spells, with [*plane shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift), and *banishment* is a 4th-level spell. How could I get back to the party without power-leveling to level 13?

Comment: Is that better in terms of explaining why I think this is a possibility?

Comment: how did your character get to the material plane in the 1st place?

Comment: Idk, I just know that I did

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Is your character actually native to the Feywild?** If they were born and raised on the Material Plane I'd have a difficult time saying they're native to anything other than the Material Plane. The spell only sends you home when "the target is native to a different plane of existence than the one you're on".

**Assuming they are, I'd talk to your DM about this.** There are many things in the game that assume all players are humanoid. An example I've run into with a fairy in my party as an Oath of the Ancients Paladin is the Turn the Faithless ability which makes fey feared for a full minute after failing an initial save with no secondary chances to save. Our DM gave that character an item so it wouldn't happen again because it made the combat especially unfun for them. Likewise, failing a single Charisma saving throw on a level 4 spell and being (essentially) permanently lost to the Feywild doesn't sound fun. Asking your DM to not do this feels reasonable.

**If you do get banished, look for [Fey Crossings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#FeyCrossings)**. There are portals between the Material Plane and the Feywild.

> Fey crossings are places of mystery and beauty on the Material Plane that have a near-perfect mirror in the Feywild, creating a portal where the two planes touch. A traveler passes through a fey crossing by entering a clearing, wading into a pool, stepping into a circle of mushrooms, or crawling under the trunk of a tree. To the traveler, it seems like he or she has simply walked into the Feywild with a step. To an observer, the traveler is there one moment and gone the next.
>
> Like other portals between planes, most fey crossings open infrequently. A crossing might open only during a full moon, on the dawn of a particular day, or for someone carrying a certain type of item. A fey crossing can be closed permanently if the land on either side is dramatically altered — for example, if a castle is built over the clearing on the Material Plane.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the DM guide, as it isn't free on DND beyond, so I didn't know about the fey crossings. Thanks for telling me about them

Comment: @Tasi All the text from the section is in the answer :)

Comment: Sometimes it is less about planning and more about trusting that the DM won't screw you over. Characters get into trouble all the time, but the DM usually provides a way out, somehow.

Comment: @SeriousBri And contrariwise, all the planning in the world won't help if the DM _is_ trying to screw you.